# New To ruby need some basic help

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

What i want to do is use my current CSS to create the home page
may basic page is like this

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="header">
    <?php include($header); ?>
</div>
<div id="nav">
    <?php include("nav.php"); ?>
</div>
<div id="main">
    main 
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
    <?php include_once"rightAD.php"; ?>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <?php include_once"footer.php"; ?>
</div>
```

what i need to know is how to replace the php includes in ruby ignore the header div tho!
oh i guess i should mention im using Rails 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the getting started section:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/

To answer you question:

Put you css file in public/stylesheets/

It will be automagically loaded.

This view is where that magic happens:

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

Comment: i do under stand that much about ruby but what i'm not sure on is how i include the banner page, the menu page, the main and the add page?

Comment: nevermind i've forgotten what little i knew about ruby i put it all in the app/views/layouts/application.html.erb its one of those brain fart days lol!

Comment: @Rod: You can use Partials to emulate your includes. Check the guides 'layout and Rendering'